# sqlite - How to use a variable in Where clause?

Tags: java, sqlite, where-clause

**EDITED** - added more code after reposnse (still not working)

I want to query sqlite with a Where clause that uses a variable but, I can't get it working.

I set a variable and pass it but, only hard coded works...

**This works:**

Penut is one of the Records in the docName column.

```
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE docName = 'Penut'");
```

**But, this does Not work:**

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dufuss.db");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
myInput ="Penut";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE docName = ?";
conn.prepareStatement(sql).setString(1, myInput);
rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
```

So, how do I get the variable *myInput* to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE docName = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, myInput);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
  // iterate through results
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post to include more code based on this response but, still not working (I also read the link mentioned below)

Comment: You're not using the `PreparedStatement` from `prepareStatement` but  rather the `Statement` object. Use the `PreparedStatement` as shown above

Answer (score 1):

try to use something like this:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use PreparedStatement. The code should look like:

```
    String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE docName = ?"              
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);

    preparedStatement.setString(1, "Penut");
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bind variables then you need to work with a prepared statement and bind the variable's value explicitly. As a placeholder for the variable you must use a ? instead of the variable's name. In your code myInput would be treated as a column name. Have a look at [Specifying a variable name in QUERY WHERE clause in JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608376/specifying-a-variable-name-in-query-where-clause-in-jdbc)